# java events using generics

Tags: java, events, generics

I am learning java generics, and trying to implement it for events
before someone asks, i have considered using polymorphism, but since I want every event to send different values to the handler's start method, I can't do this.

This is my event handler:

```
    public class MyHandler {
      public void startEventAction(int num) {
        //do something with num
      }  
    }
```

This is my template event:

```
     public abstract class SomeEvent<E> {
       protected List<E> handler_list = new LinkedList<E>();
       public SomeEvent() {
       }
       public Boolean addHandler(E handler) {
          return handler_list.add(handler);
       }
       public Boolean removeHandler(E handler) {
          return handler_list.remove(handler);
       } 
     }
```

and the event itself is: (now i know it's probably wrong to extend the SomeEvent like this, but it seems to work)

```
    public class MyEvent<MyHandler> extends SomeEvent<MyHandler> {
      public void executeHandlers() {   
        for (MyHandler handler : handler_list) {
            //Exception here!!
            handler.startEventAction(num);
        }
      }
    }
```

My question is how is it right to extend it and why does the function startEventAction doesn't exist for MyHandler in the last code block(for MyEvent)
Answers will be very much appreciated.

Comment: There is no such thing as templates in Java. It is called generics and  is nothing like templates in `c++` for example.

Comment: ok sorry about that, I know it's generics, but that is just semantics..I know about the differences, but that is not my question

Comment: not related to the question, but you have a bug or a typo (copy paste?) in the removeHandler method. You use add() instead of remove() there.

Comment: ok i fixed the typo, and someone answered the actual question, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be

```
public class MyEvent<T extends MyHandler> extends SomeEvent<T> {
      public void executeHandlers() {   
        for (T handler : handler_list) {
            //Exception here!!
            handler.startEventAction(lvc_count);
        }
    }
```

If you use `MyEvent<MyHandler>` you're considering `MyHandler` as a type parameter, not as a type argument. That's why I typically rather use letters as type paramers instead of entire words, this avoids the confusion between them and classes and interfaces names.

Comment: thank you very much, it seems to work, i just need to test it now :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the `MyEvent` class declaration:

```
public static class MyEvent extends SomeEvent<MyHandler> { ... }
```

and it should be fine.